# check whether there is a focus on the elements

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 3 textbox. How can i know which one of them has the focus?

```
 if (TextBoxExtendedSearchName.Focus() == false && 
     TextBoxExtendedSearchNomenclature.Focus() == false 
      && TextBoxExtendedSearchSpecialist.Focus() == false)
      {
                window.Close();
      }
```

this does not work

I Use WPF

```
private void TextBox1_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!TextBox1.IsFocused && !TextBox2.IsFocused)
                MessageBox.Show("Not Focus");
        }

        private void TextBox2_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!TextBox1.IsFocused && !TextBox2.IsFocused)
                MessageBox.Show("Not Focus");
        }
```

this example not work

I think I understand what the problem is. it does not work when I'm doing it in the event Lost Focus.

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void TextBox1_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!TextBox1.IsFocused && !TextBox2.IsFocused)
                MessageBox.Show("Not Focus");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Yes Focus");
        }

        private void TextBox2_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!TextBox1.IsFocused && !TextBox2.IsFocused)
                MessageBox.Show("Not Focus");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Yes Focus");
        }
```

**XAml**

```
<Window x:Class="TrainWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="62,61,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="205" LostFocus="TextBox1_LostFocus"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBox2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="62,145,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="205" LostFocus="TextBox2_LostFocus"/>
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="267,249,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="96" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Height="37">
            <Button.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="0.397"/>
                    <TranslateTransform/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Button.RenderTransform>
        </Button>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

this does not work

I understand it's my logical error

Comment: `if (!TextBoxExtendedSearchName.Focused && !TextBoxExtendedSearchNomenclature.Focused && !TextBoxExtendedSearchSpecialist.Focused)
                window.Close();`

Comment: It works in lost focus, I have tried it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
//Logical focus
 var focusedControl = FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(this);

//KeyBoard focus
 var focusedControl =  Keyboard.FocusedElement;

// dummy logic to close the window when all the three textboxes are not focused.
List<TextBox> items=new List<TextBox>();
items.Add(TextBoxExtendedSearchName);
items.Add(TextBoxExtendedSearchNomenclature);
items.Add(TextBoxExtendedSearchSpecialist);
if(!items.Any(o=>o==focusedControl))
 {
    window.Close();
 }
```

Comment: Did you get compile time error or runtime? what does the property IsFocused has?

Comment: I do not get any errors. Logic does not work properly

Comment: Logical is simple. I have check whether the focus of my textbox

Comment: you can get the focused element as i did in the answer, later on its up to you how to use it.

Comment: lemme try this out. I will keep you posted.

Comment: Its working correctly for me. Can you add the whole solution xaml & the code behind.

Comment: Yes I did.it works. same as yours , I added three textBoxes & checked Keyboard.focusedElement, this shows the element which currently has focus.

Comment: `items.Any(o=>o==focusedControl)` - if one or more item is equal to focusedControl than true. Your comment says that it should work otherwise. Maybe you should add negation in your `if` condition.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong function. You need to use the `IsFocused` property to get it a `Control` has a focus.

See the documentation here: [Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.isfocused(v=vs.110).aspx)

With your code:

```
 if (!TextBoxExtendedSearchName.IsFocused
     && !TextBoxExtendedSearchNomenclature.IsFocused
     && !TextBoxExtendedSearchSpecialist.IsFocused)
     {
        window.Close();
     }
```

This will `Close` the window if none of them has a `Focus`.

Comment: I use WPF, but not winforms. WPF no property Focused.

Comment: Edited the post! It's `IsFocused` in WPF @VladimirKombarov